# Canonical Pyramid Polynomials

Tags: geometry, polynomials, polyhedra, solid-geometry

In a [canonical polyhedron](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CanonicalPolyhedra/), all edges are tangent to a unit sphere with the origin at the center of gravity of the points of tangency.

I've been working on exact forms of canonical polyhedra, and the [regular pyramid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularPyramid.html) turned out to be an interesting case. For a base with $n$ sides, that polygon has $z$ coordinates of $-tan(\frac{\pi}{2n})$, and the apex is at $(0,0,cot(\frac{\pi}{2n}))$. Here are some examples, each pyramid with its dual. The edges are perpendicular to each other at points tangent to the unit sphere. 
[image: canonical pyramids]

The base regular polygon needs a scaling factor that is the root of a particular polynomial.  For bases with 3 to 12 sides, here are the roots and their polynomials.

$\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & 1.6329931618554520655 & 2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \\
 4 & 1.2871885058111652495 & x^4+8 x^2-16 \\
 5 & 1.1690009178779524258 & 5 x^4+40 x^2-64 \\
 6 & 1.1124766546017998270 & 3 x^4+48 x^2-64 \\
 7 & 1.0806190099881630969 & 7 x^6-448 x^2+512 \\
 8 & 1.0607630605786609417 & x^8+32 x^6+64 x^4-1024 x^2+1024 \\
 9 & 1.0475038619623609305 & 3 x^6+72 x^4+384 x^2-512 \\
 10 & 1.0381901644398379801 & 5 x^8+240 x^6+960 x^4-5120 x^2+4096 \\
 11 & 1.0313884014418166375 & 11 x^{10}+88 x^8-2112 x^6-11264 x^4+45056 x^2-32768 \\
 12 & 1.0262650635674814921 & x^8+64 x^6+128 x^4-4096 x^2+4096 \\
\end{array}$

Here's code for calculating the pyramids.

```
pyramid[basesides_] := Module[{k = Abs[basesides], poly, 
  sign = Sign[basesides], g},
  poly = RootReduce[g /. Last[Solve[myNorm[Mean[Table[{g Cos[2 Pi n/k], 
        g Sin[2 Pi n/k], -Tan[Pi/(2 k)]}, {n, 0, 1}]]] == 1]]];
  {Append[Table[{RootReduce[poly Cos[2 Pi n/k + (sign - 1) Pi/k/2]], 
  RootReduce[poly Sin[2 Pi n/k + (sign - 1) Pi/k/2]], -sign Tan[
    Pi/(2 k)]}, {n, 0, k - 1}], {0, 0, sign Cot[Pi/(2 k)]}],
  Polygon[Prepend[Sort[Append[RotateLeft[Append[Reverse[#], k + 1], 1] & /@ 
    Partition[Range[k], 2, 1], {1, k, k + 1}]], Range[k]]]}]
```

I use Solve in that.  Is there a more direct way for generating these polynomials?  Is it a known class?

Here are factored forms of the coefficients.

[image: polynomial coefficients]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h$ be the height of the pyramid, $r$ the radius of its base and $x$ the distance from the center $O$ of the tangent unit sphere to the base. The apothem of the base is then $rc$, where I introduced the shortcut $c=\cos(\pi/n)$.

The condition that the distance from $O$ to a lateral edge is $1$ gives the equation 
$$r^2(h-x)^2=r^2+h^2.$$ 
The condition that the distance from $O$ to a base edge is $1$ gives the equation 
$$x^2+r^2c^2=1.$$ 
Finally, the condition that $O$ is the barycenter of the tangency points gives the equation 
$$h-2x=hc.$$ 
These three equations can be solved for the unknowns $r$, $h$ and $x$, here's the result:
$$
r=\sqrt{2\over c(1+c)},\quad
h=2\sqrt{1\over 1-c^2},\quad
x=\sqrt{1-c\over 1+c}.
$$
Your scaling factor is of course the value of $r$, which can be calculated from the above formula, without solving complicated polynomial equations:
$$
r=\sqrt{2\over \cos(\pi/n)(1+\cos(\pi/n))}.
$$

I suspect your equations may arise from the search of an exact value for $\cos(\pi/n)$, but have little to do with canonical pyramids.

Comment: That's gorgeous.  I'll take the trig-based answer.